# DNS does not work after upgrading to OSX Yosemite

Tags: dns, osx-yosemite, bonjour

After upgrading to Yosemite I can no longer get online. I can pick an IP address on the web and get a response but DNS is not working. A ping command to google.com will fail, however an nslookup or dig request will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution but running:
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist 
followed by
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist

appears to be solving it temporarily. From what I can understand some program on my computer is trying to use mDNSResponder which is no longer used in Yosemite. Someone feel free to correct me or improve upon this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/resolver/ directory and delete files there.